# How to create files with specific security permissions in Linux? (i.e. the equivalent of Win32 CreateFile+SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)

Tags: c, linux, security, winapi, acl

With Windows' Win32 API it's possible to create files and assign to them proper security permissions (e.g. some users can read from and write to the file, other users in another group can only read but not write, etc.), using [`CreateFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and its [`SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379560(v=vs.85).aspx) parameter.

Does Linux offer something similar? Which functions and data structures should be used for that purpose?
(I can be missing something, but the classical C `fopen()` does not seem to offer a similar security permission setting feature...)

**EDIT**
Just to clarify, I'm looking for something like [Windows **ACL**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374872.aspx).

Comment: Are you looking for the simple [Unix modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_%28Unix%29) or something more advanced like [ACL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) (like Windows)?

Comment: @cremno: I'm looking for something like Windows ACL, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most recent file systems under Linux support ACL.

However ACL support needs to be enabled via the according entry to `/etc/fstab`, when [mounting the file-system](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html).

To get and set ACL from the command line use

- [getfacl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/getfacl.1.html)
- [setfacl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/setfacl.1.html)

On how to access ACL programmatically see [`man 5 acl`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/acl.5.html).

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for file attributes and ownership, there's [chmod() or fchmod()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chmod.2.html) and [chown() or fchown()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chown.2.html). There's also SELinux which has [setfilecon()](http://www.polarhome.com/service/man/?qf=setfilecon&af=0&tf=2&of=Mageia) and a few other API functions. Just note that not every Unix computer has SELinux enabled.

Comment: `chmod`/`chown` will not secure objects similar to [Access Control Lists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374872.aspx) on Windows. They will merely set the read/write/execute flags for a fixed set of user groups.